# Mockito Java: How to test a method which calls other class to retrieve value

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to test a method intialize transaction where the method creates a unique transaction Id. This method uses reference of other class to retrieve the properties.

After mocking the reference classes am still getting null pointer exception. when i try to test. Below is my code.

Note: JMockito

Any help appreciated

```
  public ResponseDto initializeTransaction(RequestDTO request){

    try {

        String transactionId =getTransactionId(request);
        ResponseDTO result = new ResponseDTO();
        result.setTransactionId(transactionId);
        return result;
        }

}

public String getTransactionId(CreditCardGwtInitializeRequestDTO request){

    StringBuffer transactionId = new StringBuffer();
    String customerId = customerIdentifier.getCustomer();
    UserDto userDto = user.getUserDetails(request.getKey());
    String userWorkStationId =userDto.getWorkStationId();
    transactionId.append(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "-"); 
    transactionId.append(userDto.getObjId()+ "-");      
    transactionId.append(transactionIdEncode.encode(customerId));
    transactionId.append("-");
    transactionId.append(transactionIdEncode.encode(userWorkStationId));    
    return transactionId.toString();    

}
```

Test class

```
public class CreditCardGwtInitializeServiceImplTest {
private CreditCardGwtInitializeServiceImpl test;
@Mock
 private CustomerIdentifier customerIdentifier;
@Mock
private UserDto userDto;
@Mock
private UserDetails user;
private CreditCardGwtInitializeRequestDTO request;
@Mock
TransactionIdCharacterEncoding transactionId;
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
}
@Test
public void when_profilename_notNull_retrieveByName() throws Exception {
    //test.setUser(user);
    CreditCardGwtInitializeResponseDTO expected = new CreditCardGwtInitializeResponseDTO();
    expected.setGatewayPassKey("");
    String profileName="theName";
    String connectionKey ="123456";
    String custId ="custId";

    request.setGatewayProfile(profileName);
    request.setConnectionKey(connectionKey);
    //userDto.setWorkStationId("12345");
    //userDto.setObjId(12345L);


    when(customerIdentifier.getCustomer()).thenReturn(custId);

    when(user.getUserDetails(anyString())).thenReturn(userDto);

    when(userDto.getWorkStationId()).thenReturn("RTYTYU");

    when(userDto.getObjId()).thenReturn(1232324L);


    when(transactionId.encode(anyString())).thenReturn("01010101");



    CreditCardGwtInitializeResponseDTO response = test.initializeTransaction(request);  
    assertEquals(expected,response );

    verifyZeroInteractions(gatewayProfileRetrievalService);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding thes lines solved my problem

```
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    test = new CreditCardGwtInitializeServiceImpl();
    test.setUser(user);
    test.setCustomerIdentifier(customerIdentifier);
    test.setTransactionIdEncode(transactionId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that uses Mockito magic instead of manual initialization (replaces the `setup` method).

First override the default JUnit Runner class by the one provided by mockito (this has the same effect as `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CreditCardGwtInitializeServiceImplTest {
...
```

then instantiate your object right after your declare it and let mockito take care of the injection (this has the same effect as the 5 lines of your solution) :

```
@InjectMocks
private CreditCardGwtInitializeServiceImpl test = new CreditCardGwtInitializeServiceImpl();
...
```